# How to set more than 2 Expression in Expression.Or

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, expression, icriteria

I want to create a query which has more than 3-4 Expression.Or ? But Expression.Or just let me to add two Expressions inside it.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
                query
                    .Add(Expression.Or(
                             Expression.Like("Name", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere),
                             Expression.Like("LastName", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere)))
                    .Add(Expression.Or(
                             Expression.Like("Email1", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere),
                             Expression.Like("Email2", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere)));
```

The code above generates "Name like %this% or LastName like %this% **AND** Email1 like %this% and Email2 like %this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following is something I found a while back for Entity Framework, the same code works with nHibernate : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554663/composing-linq-to-entity-query-from-multiple-parameters/1554759#1554759

Comment: @Alexandre: your solution is for a LINQ provider. This question is about the NHibernate Criteria API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Disjunction](http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Expression/Disjunction.html) instead of Or.

Comment: Thank you very much,

I have another question. I want to query another table while querying this one. Forexample i want to get Customers whose id = Group.CustomerId

Comment: Please create another question for that, it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: I really don't understand the point of using Disjunction when you have the Linq api and Expressions

Comment: @Alexandre: take a good look at the date of the question and answer. Also, the question is tagged with 'criteria'

Comment: @Alexandre: if there was a LINQ provider for NHibernate back then, it was the contrib provider which was quite broken. Criteria API was much more widely used. The built-in LINQ provider is a relatively recent addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use || instead of Or( ) or Disjunction( ).