# Composing Linq to Entity Query from multiple parameters

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently building a detailed search and I am trying to figure out how to compose my Linq query to my Entity.

basically I have users that can select 1* items in a list control. 
the part I can't wrap my head around is the following:

how can I dynamically build a **Where** AND( field is equal to this OR field is equal to this OR...) clause
where the number of items is variant.

database **Domain** Field sample content : '26, 21, 22, 100, 164, 130'

**Example**: (The idea is to be able to generate this depending on the number of items selected)

```
Offre.Where(o=> o.Domain.Contains("26") || o.Domain.Contains("100") )

Offre.Where(o=> o.Domain.Contains("26") )

Offre.Where(o=> o.Domain.Contains("26") || o.Domain.Contains("100") || o.Domain.Contains("22") )
```

then I can easily have the resulting query as an IQueryable and add on to this object to build my query.

can someone point me inthe right direction for my AND ( OR .. OR ) clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To work around this restriction, you can manually construct an expression (Source)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/)

**C#**

```
static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(

    Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)

{

    if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }

    if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

    ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

    // p => valueSelector(p) == values[0] || valueSelector(p) == ...

    if (!values.Any())

    {

        return e => false;

    }

    var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);

}
```

Using this utility method,

```
var query2 = context.Entities.Where(BuildContainsExpression<Entity, int>(e => e.ID, ids));
```

**VB.Net**

```
Public Shared Function BuildContainsExpression(Of TElement, TValue)( _
ByVal valueSelector As Expression(Of Func(Of TElement, TValue)), _
ByVal values As IEnumerable(Of TValue) _
   ) As Expression(Of Func(Of TElement, Boolean))

    ' validate arguments
    If IsNothing(valueSelector) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("valueSelector")
    If IsNothing(values) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("values")

    Dim p As ParameterExpression = valueSelector.Parameters.Single()
    If Not values.Any Then
        Return _
            Function(e) False
    End If

    Dim equals = values.Select( _
        Function(v) _
            Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(v, GetType(TValue))) _
    )

    Dim body = equals.Aggregate( _
        Function(accumulate, equal) _
            Expression.Or(accumulate, equal) _
    )

    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of TElement, Boolean))(body, p)
End Function
```

Using this utility method

```
   Dim query = m_data. Offer

   If (selectedSectors.Count > 0) Then
        query = query.Where(BuildContainsExpression(Function(o As Offer) o.Value, selectedSectors))
   End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your answer:

[LINQ to entities - Building where clauses to test collections within a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110314/linq-to-entities-building-where-clauses-to-test-collections-within-a-many-to-ma#131551)

Answer (score 0):

If your Offre has some kind of unique Id associated with it, you could try the following:

```
List<int> queryCriteria = new List<int>;

//Fill your query criteria here

//Instead of o.Domain.Id you can use whatever ID you have.
var resultSet = Offre.Where(o => queryCriteria.Contains(o.Domain.Id));
```

Comment: This is good when you are doing Linq to Objects, but I want my query to execute completely on the SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, my boss keeps calling objects entities, so I keep mixing those two up.