# ICriteria.Add like OR

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following code:

```
foreach (CheckedListBoxItem item in cbAttributes.Items)
    {
        if (item.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
               if ((string)item.Value == "Category" || (string)item.Value == "Kgs" || (string)item.Value == "Mks" || (string)item.Value == "Author")
                    {
                        var alias = item.Value.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
                        criteria.CreateAlias(item.Value.ToString(), alias);

                        criteria.Add(Expression.Like(alias + ".Name", "%" + meTextToFind.Text + "%"));
                    }                       
            }
    }
```

The criteria after loop looks like:

```
C.Name like %text% AND K.Name like %text%
```

The problem is that I need to `OR` instead `AND`. How can i do this?
PS. Version of Nhibernate is **1.2.1.400**.

Comment: "Very older"? Can you tell us the *actual* version of NHibernate you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Expression.Or(Expression.Like("param", param), Expression.Like("param", param))
```

If you need more then 2 expression in `Or` statement, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434138/how-to-set-more-than-2-expression-in-expression-or) (using Disjunction)

**update**

Described here: [How to create OR statements for NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386308/how-to-create-or-statements-for-nhibernate?sort=oldest#sort-top)

```
.Add(
  Expression.Disjunction()
    .Add(criteria)
    .Add(other_criteria)
)
```